Does this diagram for cardiac monitor make any sense?
My teacher diagrammed this cardiac monitor for us to assemble it and make it work for final project. I already built it with the exact same components, but I can't manage to make it work.
I designed it in KiCad because she diagrammed it for us with a pen on a sheet of a paper. We have started to think that this is the first time she has assigned something like this to her students, not even she knows if it will work.



Could it be that the LED and phototransistor pair are intended to be separate parts rather than an optocoupler?  There's no input that I can see for electrocardiogram (ECG) electrodes.  An LED and a phototransistor placed together pointing in the same direction could be used to detect the flow of blood in an artery.

@JRE CNY70 is not an optocoupler. It's a reflective optical sensor, with LED and a phototransistor pointing in the same direction.

Do you have an oscilloscope? Have you looked at the signals? You must, and you have to edit the question to add the signals to it. Go step-by-step. Start by adding a voltage follower to the collector of the pletysmograph and see if you have some signal there, with AC coupling. It should be easily visible on the oscilloscope at 5..10mV/div.

What was the task - finalize the circuit? Build it? How have you even powered it, with three lab power supply channels and how? Just thinking if the problem is not the circuit given to you but how you implemented it and use it.

Do you have a pletysmographic sensor that clips on a finger, or are you making your own? I highly suggest to use a pre-made sensor. They are discarded once the patient doesn't need them, so you should be able to get a used one or two for free, just disinfect it well. I had a few from my own family's hospital visits, but unfortunately I have thrown them away. Otherwise I'd send them to you.

You also should add photos of your assembled circuit, and of the sensor you're using - including a photo of how you clip it on a finger. It is possible you're making some simple mistake.

@Justme Wow, shows that I was an ass for assuming that "CNYxx, oh it must be a generic optocoupler".

I've labelled your schematic with some node names A to E and block numbers 1 to 5, to help with diagnosis. I will refer to node potentials as \$V_A\$, \$V_B\$ etc.

In my opinion, the most obscure and difficult block to test and diagnose is block 1, because R1 and R2 need to have exactly the right values for your particular optical device. Even if everything else is working just fine, it all relies on the photo-transistor operating in its active region, neither saturated nor cut-off, where \$V_A\$ is sat somewhere near the +2.5V midpoint. With \$R_2=10k\Omega\$, that occurs when collector current \$I_C\$ is:
$$ I_C = \frac{5V-V_A}{R_2} = \frac{5V - 2.5V}{10k\Omega} = 250uA $$
This will require you to choose R1 with great care. Let's say that when a finger is present on the optical device, reflecting LED light strongly onto the photo-transistor, and the ratio between LED current \$I_{LED}\$ and collector current \$I_C\$ is 5%:
$$ I_C = 5\% \times I_{LED} $$
Rearranging that and plugging in the desired bias current \$I_C=250\mu A\$, we can find the necessary LED current:
$$ I_{LED} = \frac{1}{5\%} \times 250\mu A = 20 \times 250\mu A = 5mA $$
To obtain this exact \$I_{LED}\$, we must consider the LED's forward voltage, which I will guess to be \$V_{LED}=2V\$. R1 would be determined as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{LED} &= \frac{V_{R1}}{R_1} \\ \\
R_1 &= \frac{V_{R1}}{I_{LED}} \\ \\
&= \frac{5V - V_{LED}}{I_{LED}} \\ \\
&= \frac{5V - 2V}{5mA} \\ \\
&= 600\Omega
\end{aligned}
$$
There's no feedback between/around blocks in this design, so those blocks can be tested in isolation. The first thing to test is op-amp outputs. You should measure the output potentials of each op-amp in turn, with an oscilloscope, and if you find any of them "stuck" near the supply potentials, then you have immediately found a problem.  With the TL07x op-amps all supplied with ±10V, these devices have output potentials limited to between about +8V and -8V. If, for example you see \$V_B=+7.8V\$, or \$V_D=-8.2V\$ this is a good indication that the op-amp is saturated, which is a problem.
As I explained above, output constraints apply to block 1. It is only able to produce a signal \$V_A\$ within \$0V < V_A < +5V\$, but ideally it needs to be around half-way, at \$V_A=+2.5V\$, for testing. You may be able to obtain a steady \$V_A\$ with careful illumination of the photo-transistor, but I would recommend cutting the path at A, and applying a test square wave  signal of amplitude 1V pk-pk, centred at +2.5V: \$V_A=+2.5V\pm 0.5V\$ directly at A using a signal generator.
Block 2 is a low-pass filter with cut-off frequency \$f=\frac{1}{2\pi RC}\approx 0.5Hz\$, so if your signal generator frequency is 0.5Hz or so, you should see something like this:

Consider using CircuitLab (or Kicad) to perform simulations for each block independently, with controlled input potentials, to see what to expect at the output. Here's the CircuitLab schematic of block 2 that I used to obtain that graph, which you can play with by clicking the "Simulate" link below it:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Block 4 is identical to block 2, and can be tested with exactly the same procedure.
You'll notice that the +2.5V offset at the input is retained at the output, because low-pass filters do not remove DC offset. This offset is removed by block 3, an instrumental amplifier which performs the following function:
$$ V_C = V_E + G(V_A - V_B) $$
Gain \$G\$ is set by adjusting RV1:
$$ G = \left( 1+\frac{22k\Omega}{RV1} \right) $$
Worryingly, it's possible to set \$RV1=0\Omega\$ which is obviously problematic, and I would have placed another resistance in series with it to impose a lower limit. As it is though, setting \$RV1=10k\Omega\$ (its maximum) will set \$G=5.4\$:
$$ V_C = V_E + 5.4(V_A - V_B) $$
This is trivial to test. Disconnect inputs A, B and E, apply three known and controlled potentials there, and check that the output \$V_C\$ obeys that relationship. You could start by grounding them all, so that \$V_A = V_B = V_E = 0V\$, and verify that \$V_C=0\$. Then modify each potential individually to see if \$V_C\$ changes accordingly. For instance, raising E to \$V_E=+1V\$ should cause output C to rise by 1V. Raising \$V_B\$ by 1V should cause C to fall by 5.4V, as suggested by the subtraction operator.
Block 5 is a simple voltage follower, producing a very low impedance source of potential adjustable between 0V and +5V. It provides an offset \$V_E\$ to be added to \$V_C\$, permitting you to adjust the "centre" potential of the final output \$V_D\$, perhaps so that you may interface it to an ADC. For example, if you have an ADC expecting a signal between 0V and +3.3V, you can set \$V_E=+1.65V\$, exactly half way between those extremes.
It's easy to test this block, just turn the potentiometer RV2 slowly from end-stop to end-stop, and verify on an oscilloscope that you do indeed obtain a steady potential going from 0V to +5V.
That's everything that went through my head as I examined the circuit, and while I will answer questions related to what I've said here, I only intend to give you pointers, not solve all the potential problems.

That's not how power flags work in KiCad. The nodes are not named PWR_FLAG and not connected together. They define that a power node is driven so that it does not warn about e.g. 12V going into power pin of an op-amp but 12V not being a power output from anywhere if it in reality comes in from a connector, as you can use any connector and for power input and output and usually connectors don't define a pin on them that is a power output to the node.

@Justme OK! I stand corrected, and I sit sheepishly down. thanks for the heads up!

Schematic is not at all clear where the ecg electrodes are connected to - or how.
EDIT:
Did not recognize the optical intput - "cardiac monitor" is kind of misleading when you measure the pulse wave.
IRL those are usually lit with switched LEDs of different wavelengths and short on-times - but those are not stricly required.

The ECG electrodes connect to nowhere, this design does not use them. It uses an optical sensor. Please fix the answer.

Multiple wavelengths such as red and IR are used in pulse oximeters which can measure blood oxygen saturation, but is not required for just getting a pulse.


Does this diagram for cardiac monitor make any sense?

The circuit uses a DC removal scheme with a low-pass filter, its output is then subtracted from the original signal with an instrumentation amplifier built out of 3 op-amps.
This idea could probably be made to work, but it seems overly complicated. I'm not sure if the pletysmographic sensor's current-to-voltage conversion is going to work well. You may get some signal, but not all what the sensor could provide. I would be surprised if it didn't work at all. The offset adjustment seems unnecessary.

but I can't manage to make it work

The general idea should work, but some choices made in the design may be unnecessarily finicky. A rudimentary simulation of this circuit could reveal what's going on - whether the simulation is done using SPICE, or entirely in human head :)

We have started to think that it's the first time of her assigning something like this to her students, not even she knows if it will work.

Her job isn't to just give you a working circuit to assemble. What would that leave for you to do? You could assemble it in an hour or two and you'd be done, just write the report... I'm sure that's not the goal of the project.
It's a final project, it can't consist of just assembling a circuit someone else designed. It's your job to understand how it was meant to work, and to make it work. What is the name of the course this final project is for?
Given that you have made no indication of understanding how this is supposed to work, do you think you're qualified to judge the circuit so prematurely?
